# Javascript calculate Points every minute between two variables as half sinus curve

Tags: javascript, math, range, interpolation, calculation

I want to create a **half sinus curve** between two points. I have a loop every minute to calculate the new value.

Start value: 6500
End value: 2700

The timerange ist for example sunrise to sunset (eg: 1673931600000 and 1673970886131)
I have the "sun minutes per day". eg. 654.76885

Now, I want to calculate **every minute** the new value. => adaptiveCtTimed

Here a example of the Curve;
[image: curve]

For a linear curve, I use the following code which works perfect.

```
sunMinutesDay = (sunset - sunrise) / 1000 / 60;
RangePerMinute = CtRange / sunMinutesDay;

if (await compareTime(adapter, sunrise, sunset, "between", ActualTime)) {
    adaptiveCtTimed = Math.round(maxCt - ((ActualTime - morningTime) / 1000 / 60) * RangePerMinute);
}
```

Comment: It may seem complicated, but you simply want to have a value `f(x)` which is `0` at `a`, and `pi` at `b`, which is `f(x)=(x-a)*Math.PI/(b-a)`, and then feed it into `sin()`, so `Math.sin((x-a)*Math.PI/(b-x))`. Side note: Sun goes around a sinus curve the whole day, which is always 24 hours, and the half of it is always 12 hours. The interval between sunrise and sunset is not necessarily 12 hours, so the visible trajectory of the Sun is not necessarily an exact half sinus either.

Comment: Thank you, but the time difference could be different. well, for example I start at 6 am and ends at sunset.